# how to cast this string list to an object

Tags: c#

If I have this string list:

```
string myObjectString = "MyObject, SetWidth, int, 10, 0, 1";
```

in which:

```
- MyObject: the object class
- SetWidth: the property of the object
- int: type of the SetWidth is int
- 10: default value
- 0: object order
- 1: property order
```

Then how can I construct an object like this:

```
[ObjectOrder(0)]
public class MyObject:
{
   private int _SetWidth = 10;

   [PropertyOrder(1)]
   public int SetWidth
   {
      set{_SetWidth=value;}
      get{return _SetWidth;}
   }
}
```

So, I would like have something like this:

```
Object myObject = ConstructAnObject(myObjectString);
```

and the `myObject` is an instance of `MyObject`. Could it be possible in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait what... You want to both generate the class and instantiate an instance of it all in one go? Or you already have the class defined and you want to just instantiate an instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some quick and dirty code to get you started:

```
        string myObjectString = "MyObject, SetWidth, int, 10, 0, 1";
        var info = myObjectString.Split(',');

        string objectName = info[0].Trim();
        string propertyName = info[1].Trim();
        string defaultValue = info[3].Trim();

        //find the type
        Type objectType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t=>t.Name.EndsWith(objectName)).Single();//might want to redirect to proper assembly

        //create an instance
        object theObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        //set the property
        PropertyInfo pi = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        object valueToBeSet = Convert.ChangeType(defaultValue, pi.PropertyType);
        pi.SetValue(theObject, valueToBeSet, null);

        return theObject;
```

This will find the MyObject, create an object of the proper propertytype, and set the matching property.

Comment: This looks nice, how can I add: [ObjectOrder(0)] and [PropertyOrder(1)]? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, as far as i know the attributes are defined on the type, not an on a single instance.

Answer (score 5):

I think you better use the Object Serialization/Deserialization instead of creating a custom method that basically needs to do the same thing

more info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to generate new types there are two possible ways to do so:

1. Using [Reflection Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx)
2. Using [CodeDom provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx#Y0)

I think the simpler solution is CodeDom provider. All needed is to generate the source as a string in memory, and then compile the code and instantiate a new instance with [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx). This is a nice [example](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/Dynamic-Code) I just found.
The reason I think that CodeDom provider is simpler is that it has shorter setup - no need to generate dynamic module and assembly and then work with type builder and members builder.  In addition, it doesn't require working with IL to generate the getter and setter bodies.
An advantage that reflection emit has is performance - dynamic module can add more types to itself even after one of the types was used. CodeDom provider requires creating all the types at once, otherwise it creates a new assembly each time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use C# 4.0, you can use the new `dynamic` feature.

```
string myObjectString = "MyObject, SetWidth, int, 10, 0, 1";
String[] properties = myObjectString.Split(',');
dynamic myObj;

myObj.MyObject = (objtect)properties[0];
myObj.SetWidth = Int32.Parse(properties[1]);

// cast dynamic to your object. Exception may be thrown.

MyObject result = (MyObject)myObj;
```

Comment: with this declaration: dynamic myObj, I think I cannot do: myObj.MyObject. If I declare: dynamic myObj = new object(); then I can 't do myObj.MyObject = (object)properties[0]

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand why do you need ObjectOrder and PropertyOrder... Once you have their names you probably don't need them, at least for "deserialization"...

Or please advice what is their role?

You definitely can simply do it via reflection:

- Split the string by comma (using myString.Split)
- Use reflection to find an object within your application:

  - Find the type with name = splittedString[0] (enumerate all the assemblies within the domain and all the types within each assembly);
  - Instantiate the type found (using Activator.CreateInstance)
- Find the property by name (Using objectType.GetProperty)
- Set the property value (using propertyInfo.SetValue)
- Return the object